# How can put the page content according to data came from another page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, get

I have a page (menu.php) that retrieves and displays data from a database including name, image, price
I want to add a link when i click on the image take me to another page (single Product.php) , so i have only one page and i want its content depending on the image i have clicked

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="products-heading">
        <h2>Our Salad</h2>
    </div>  <!-- End of /.Products-heading -->
    <div class="product-grid">
    <div class="row">
            <?php
                require('connection.php');
                extract($_POST);

                $rc=mysql_query("select * from menu where Item_Catagory = 'Salad'") or die(mysql_error());
                while($MenuItem=mysql_fetch_array($rc))
                {

                ?>
                <!--To send item info to single-product page -->

                <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="products">

                        <a href="single-product.php" >
                            <img src="images/<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_Image']; ?>"  alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="single-product.php">
                            <h4> <?php echo $MenuItem['Item_Name']?> </h4>
                        </a>
                        <p class="price"> <?php echo $MenuItem['Item_Price']?></p>
                        <div class="row lead">
                            <center><div id="stars" class="starrr"></div></center>
                        </div>
                        <a class="view-link shutter" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Add To Cart</a>
                    </div>  <!-- End of /.products -->
                </div> <!-- End Of /.Col-md-4 -->    

        <?php }

        ?>

    </div>  <!-- End of /.row -->
```

this is a part of the first page
I want to use get method to send the data to the another page, but i do not what is the appropriate method should i use javascript?if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use id's to send data:

`<a class="view-link shutter" href="Product.php?id="<?= $MenuItem['id'];?>">`

In the other page `$dataID = $_GET[id];` than query your DB `where id=$dataID`

Answer (score 0):

change  `<a href="single-product.php">`

to `<a href="single-product.php?name=<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_Name']?>">`

An example redirect would now be "single-product.php?name=food"

In single-product.php you could now retrieve the itemname with $_GET (superglobal).
In your script you would get it by `$item = $_GET['name']`, $item is now equal to 'food'.

To get information about this particular product "food", you query the database in single-product.php like so: "select * from menu where Item_Name = '".$item."'". Now append the result into your html.

To do this by ajax you would need to handle all the anchor tags, assuming you are using jQuery the following will do:

```
$('a').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(response){

            console.log(response);

            //here you can append the response to your html
        }
    });

    return false; //prevent browser from redirecting
});
```